# How to use table created using TPH in entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Domain Model

```
 public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Something1 { get; set; }
    public int Something2 { get; set; }
    public string Something3 { get; set; }
}

public class PQR1 : BaseClass
{
    public int value1 { get; set; }
}


public class PQR2 : BaseClass
{
    public int value2 { get; set; }
}


public class PQR3 : BaseClass
{
    public int value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Context Class

```
 public class PQRContext : DbContext
{
    public PQRContext() : base ("PQR")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<BaseClass> Baseclass { get; set; }




    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

      modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>().
          Map<PQR1>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("Value1"))
          .Map<PQR2>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("Value2"))
          .Map<PQR3>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("Value3"));
    }
}
```

It'll create table like this:

[image]

But I don't know how to use this table while coding, I get stuck like this 
[image]

So I can't access to another classes like PQR1, PQR2,PQR3 where as I have no reason to insert data into base class which is already abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First option :**

You are not restricted on `DbSet` creations. You can create many `DbSet` as much as you need for your derived classes like the code below and access them like you will do with other `DbSet` :

```
public DbSet<BaseClass> Baseclass { get; set; }
public DbSet<PQR1> PQR1s { get; set; }
public DbSet<PQR2> PQR2s { get; set; }
public DbSet<PQR3> PQR3s { get; set; }
```

You use the `DbSet` related to the derived you want for inserting into or requesting your context.

**Second option :**

For querying your context and get only the desired subclass entities you can use the generic method `OfType<T>` which act as a filter like this:

```
var myBaseClassList = myContext.BaseClass; // Retrieve all PQR1, PQR2 and PQR3 entities
var myPQR1List = myContext.BaseClass.OfType<PQR1>(); // Retrieve all PQR1
var myPQR2List = myContext.BaseClass.OfType<PQR2>(); // Retrieve all PQR2
var myPQR3List = myContext.BaseClass.OfType<PQR3>(); // Retrieve all PQR3
```

For inserting you can create an instance of your derived class and add it directly to your base class `DbSet` :

```
var pqr1 = new PQR1() {  /* set my properties */ };
myCOntext.BaseClass.Add(pqr1); // EF knows how to insert data for classes that use TPH.
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's really helpful.

Comment: Hey, how can seed data into above tables? @CodeNotFound